# HTML/CSS overflow ellipses with lists

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a big block of text including a list `<li> </li>` that I'd like to hide in ellipses overflow. However, I realize that when the `<li>` element is nested in a `<span>` for which I've added the overflow and ellipses properties to, it won't apply to the `<li>` element! i.e., the list will not be hidden within the ellipses as overflow, it still gets displayed.

What is a workaround here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a `<li>` element inside a span. `<li>` elements must stay directly under the `<ul>` tag. And, `text-overflow` does not works on inline elements (the default display for a span). For the text overflow, try this:

```css
li {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit consectetur</li>
  <li><span>Loremconsectetur ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</span></li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum, consectetur</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To add to what @Mattia Astorino said, you also **must** have a `width` or a `max-width` on the element. Otherwise it won't know when to add the ellipsis. He demonstrated that in his code.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't express my problem correctly. The list is part of a larger block of text that I'd like to hide overflow in elipses - looks like ```text text text <li> </li> </li> </li>```. I want the elipses to apply to that entire block of text AND bulleted list as one whole thing. The problem is, the hiding elipses only apply to the text and not the list.  I already have the width/max-width property